# Auto repair loop triggered by failed system restore

Tags: windows-10, system-restore

I was having connection issues with my PC and attempted to use a restore point to fix the issue, however it would seem the restore point failed and completely destroyed my computer. Upon finishing it's attempt at restoring the system the Computer shut down unexpectedly - I say 'unexpectedly' because it gave me the message below:

[Your PC has ran into a problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SoN1.jpg)

When the computer restarted it was locked in a loop in which "Auto-repair" repeatedly failed to fix the system. I attempted to undo the restore but the Undo failed. Does anyone know how I should move forward?

I should probably clarify further by noting that, as far as I can tell, I'm stuck in a Auto repair loop as a result of a failed system restore.

I'm unable to undo the restore as attempting to do so results in a 0X80070003

Answer (score 0):

**If you do not have a backup image of the HDD**, your best option is to *save any salvageable files* using [Test Disk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) or an [alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/testdisk/). Then download [the Windows 10 ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10) and follow the directions to create a bootable USB flash drive.

- You *might* be able to reinstall Windows, svaing your files, following [AOMEI's *Method 3*](https://www.backup-utility.com/windows-10/reinstall-windows-10-without-losing-data-4348.html).
- You can try a full installation, if above fails.
- If the installation from the ISO fails, you will likely need to reformat and/or repartition the HDD, but doing so will remove your Windows 10 license. That leaves you with a few choices:

  - Get the original Windows 10 CD, if available.
  - [Buy a Windows 10 license.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-10-home/d76qx4bznwk4/1NT3)
  - Try a different operating system, such as Linux. You can [download Ubuntu](http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/), for example, and run it from a USB flash drive without installation to see if you like it. You might also use it to recover files from the HDD. After trying it without installation, you then have the option to actually install to the HDD.

Comment: I take it that there is no way to try a different restore point are fix the attempted one?

Comment: @user1007908 - You have a serious problem unlikely solved by a restore point, you can try, after you recover files that are important to you

Comment: Could I potentially boot up using a flash drive with Ubuntu? If so can you point me in the right direction of a method that allows me to do so without reaching desktop?

Comment: Yes, you can use Ubuntu installation media to access your disk. Follow the PC manufacturer's instructions for entering BIOS/UEFI and changing boot order, enabling USB, etc. When you boot this way, the HDD will be read-only, a safety feature.